# Jest - Referencing local files gives package link error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a React native SDK-type project that has the following rough structure:

```
project  
│
└───src
│   └───__tests__
│   │   │   manager.test.txt
│   │
│   └───dictation
│        │   manager.ts
│        │   ...
│        └───src
│            └───exampleFileStream.ts               
│    
└───lib
│   │   ...
│   
└───package.json
└───sdk.podspec
...
```

Where exampleFileStream is a audio file stream class that references native modules, and is referenced in my `manager.ts` class file.

My `package.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "sdk-test-project",
  "version": "0.1.3",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.tsx",
  "module": "lib/module/index",
  "types": "lib/typescript/index.d.ts",
  "react-native": "src/index",
  "source": "src/index",
  "files": [...
  ],
  "scripts": {...},
  "keywords": [
    "react-native",
    "ios",
    "android"
  ],
  "repository": "...",
  "author": "...",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "...",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@arkweid/lefthook": "^0.7.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.2",
    "@release-it/conventional-changelog": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.6.1",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "0.68.0",
    "commitlint": "^17.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "jest-websocket-mock": "^2.4.0",
    "pod-install": "^0.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-builder-bob": "^0.18.3",
    "release-it": "^15.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.21"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "*",
    "react-native": "*"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/example/node_modules",
      "<rootDir>/lib/"
    ],
    "modulePaths": ["<rootDir>/app/"]

  },
  "commitlint": {
    "extends": [
      "@commitlint/config-conventional"
    ]
  },
  "release-it": {
    "git": {
      "commitMessage": "chore: release ${version}",
      "tagName": "v${version}"
    },
    "npm": {
      "publish": true
    },
    "github": {
      "release": true
    },
    "plugins": {
      "@release-it/conventional-changelog": {
        "preset": "angular"
      }
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {...},
  "eslintIgnore": [...],
  "prettier": {...},
  "react-native-builder-bob": {
    "source": "src",
    "output": "lib",
    "targets": [
      "commonjs",
      "module",
      [
        "typescript",
        {
          "project": "tsconfig.build.json"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Inside my problem test file I am currently trying to import the manager class as follows:

```
import WS from "jest-websocket-mock";
import { Manager } from '../../src/dictation/manager';


test('When onApiMessage enabled, only the callback is called', async () => {
    const server = new WS("ws://localhost:1234");
    const dm = Manager.method("");
    ...
});
```

When I try and run jest, I get the following error that makes my test file fail:

```
 The package 'sdk-test-project' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure: 

    - You have run 'pod install'
    - You rebuilt the app after installing the package
    - You are not using Expo managed workflow

      15 |       {
      16 |         get() {
    > 17 |           throw new Error(LINKING_ERROR);
         |                 ^
      18 |         },
      19 |       }
      20 |     );

      at Object.get (src/dictation/core/exampleFileStream:17:17)
      at new addListener (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js:53:45)
      at new ExampleFileStream (src/dictation/core/exampleFileStream:37:26)
      at new Manager (src/dictation/manager.ts:116:32)
      at Function.fromCustomUrl (src/dictation/manager.ts:104:12)
      at fromCustomUrl (src/__tests__/manager.test.tsx:13:33)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:86:17)
      at Generator._invoke (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:66:24)
      at Generator.next (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:117:21)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:86:17)
```

I don't understand how the problem can be down to linking, as I am locally referencing files that are in the same project as the test file??? Is it something to do with native modules?

Comment: you can follow the issue and link your project, cd ios && pod install

Comment: That doesn't work, I get 'No Podfile found in the project directory'. The project is more of an SDK than a fully fledged mobile app

Comment: I may not be able to assist then since I have not done native development before